# How to boost a SOLR document when indexing with /solr/update

Tags: solr, apache-tika, solr-cell

To index my website, I have a Ruby script that in turn generates a shell script that uploads every file in my document root to Solr. The shell script has many lines that look like this:

```
  curl -s \
 "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=/about/core-team/&commit=false" \
 -F "myfile=@/extra/www/docroot/about/core-team/index.html"
```

...and ends with:

```
curl -s http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data-binary \
'<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

This uploads all documents in my document root to Solr. I  use [tika and ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) to upload documents in various formats (primarily PDF and HTML) to Solr.

In the script that generates this shell script, I would like to boost certain documents based on whether their id field (a/k/a url) matches certain regular expressions.

Let's say that these are the boosting rules (pseudocode):

```
boost = 2 if url =~ /cool/
boost = 3 if url =~ /verycool/
# otherwise we do not specify a boost
```

What's the simplest way to add that index-time boost to my http request?

I tried:

```
curl -s \
 "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=/verycool/core-team/&commit=false" \
 -F "myfile=@/extra/www/docroot/verycool/core-team/index.html" \
 -F boost=3
```

and:

```
curl -s \
 "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=/verycool/core-team/&commit=false" \
 -F "myfile=@/extra/www/docroot/verycool/core-team/index.html" \
 -F boost.id=3
```

Neither made a difference in the ordering of search results. What I want is for the boosted results to come first in search results, regardless of what the user searched for (provided of course that the document contains their query).

I understand that if I POST in XML format I can specify the boost value for either the entire document or a specific field. But If I do that, it isn't clear how to specify a file as the document contents. Actually, the [tika page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) provides a partial example:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc5&defaultField=text" \
--data-binary @tutorial.html -H 'Content-type:text/html'
```

But again it isn't clear where/how to specify my boost. I tried:

```
curl \ 
"http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=mydocid&defaultField=text&boost=3"\
--data-binary @mydoc.html -H 'Content-type:text/html'
```

and

```
curl \ 
"http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=mydocid&defaultField=text&boost.id=3"\
--data-binary @mydoc.html -H 'Content-type:text/html'
```

Neither of which altered search results.

Is there a way to update just the boost attribute of a document (not a specific field) without altering the document contents? If so, I could accomplish my goal in two steps:
1) Upload/index document as I have been doing
2) Specify boost for certain documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To index a document in Solr, you have to POST it to the /update handler. The documents to index are put in the body of the POST request. In general, you have to use the [xml format format of Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages). Using that xml, you can add a boost value to a specific field or to a whole document.

Comment: I've been getting by until now without using the XML format. If I use the XML format, how do I upload a file (PDF or HTML) as the document body?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice you were using the ExtractingHandler... The syntax you use to specify a boost on a field is correct (boost.field=value). But I notice that you are boosting the id field. To be effective, an index-time boost should be on a field that you will query on (see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts).

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it to work doing something like this: 
`curl -s "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=/mydoc.html&commit=false&boost.text=3" -F "myfile=@mydoc.html"`
I also had to change my search form to explicitly search the 'text' field which is where tika puts all contents of PDFs, etc. Thanks.